# Are all gradient fields conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I can see that path independence is the same as saying the work down in a closed loop is 0.  I'm Ok with that but what special property does the gradient field have that insures path does not matter when calculating it's line integral. There must be some special feature doing this?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: [Generalised Stokes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem)

Comment: that will do ...I will check out the fundamental theorem on line integrals ...maybe the features of the gradient are there...that you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special property is that it is a gradient field. Note that for an arbitrary vector field ${\bf F}=(F_1,F_2,F_3)$ you can choose independently  *three* functions $F_i$ of three variables, whereas to produce a gradient field you can only choose *one* function $f$ of three variables and then put ${\bf F}:=\nabla f$.

Comment: interesting statement ....you may be onto something.   One last missing piece ...for the gradient...the partial of x and then the partial of y is the same as the reverse order partial of y and partial of x.  The key to what I seek is here somewhere to tie together , exact vs inexact differential AND gradient ...give me a little push